# How to add a new html element through widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm trying to find a widget that can insert new video html.

It is for flutter web. I have javascript running in a website. Now I'm trying to reuse the javascipt in a website using flutter. dart:js package is used to invoke JS functions. Those JS functions manipulate two video element in a web page. So I need to create a widget that inserts video element. Below is the code for the video widget.

```cs
class ElementWidget extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
    .....
    @override
    RenderHTMLElement createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
        return RenderHTMLElement(tagName,properties);
    }
}

class RenderHTMLElement extends RenderProxyBox {
    ......
    @override
    void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
        if (child != null) {
            context.paintChild(child, offset);
        }

        StringBuffer buffer = StringBuffer();

        if (_properties != null) {
            for (String key in _properties.keys) {
                buffer.write(" '$key'='${_properties[key]}'");
            }
         }

         ParagraphBuilder builder = ParagraphBuilder(null);
         builder.addText("<$_tagName ${buffer.toString()}></${_tagName}>");

         context.canvas.drawParagraph(builder.build(), offset);
    }
}
```

In web source, video element is not there.

Any idea on how to archive it?

Comment: Please have a look at https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is an [available package](https://pub.dev/) that lets you render HTML into Flutter widget tree. Try to explored the plugin [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html). This also allow CSS to be rendered as Flutter widgets.

> This package is designed with simplicity in mind. Originally created
> to allow basic rendering of HTML content into the Flutter widget tree,
> this project has expanded to include support for basic styling as
> well! If you need something more robust and customizable, the package
> also provides a number of optional custom APIs for extremely granular
> control over widget rendering!